# Disable warning messages about ntpd in syslog

Tags: 16.04, syslog, ntp

I start my computer with internet disable and noticed that syslog is full of warning messages about ntpd

```
ntpd[1123]: error resolving pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
ntpd[1123]: error resolving pool 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
ntpd[1123]: error resolving pool 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
ntpd[1123]: error resolving pool 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
ntpd[1123]: error resolving pool ntp.ubuntu.com: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)
```

How do i disable these warnings in syslog?

Comment: Use `dpkg -L ntp\*` to see which `ntp` packages are installed. Uninstall (with `sudo apt purge ...`.

Comment: ntp is vital, just wanna hide those messages in syslog.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding this in the ntpd config file (/etc/ntp.conf):

```
logconfig = -clockall -peerall -sysall -syncall
```

According to the manual, it should have prevented all logging but I still saw the "error resolving" messages appearing in syslog.

The only way I managed to stop the messages was by starting ntpd with the -l option and sending log file output to /dev/null:

```
ntpd -l /dev/null
```